# Toggle visibility with JQuery FOREACH row returned in cshtml

Tags: jquery, razor, foreach, webmatrix

I've searched high and low for the answer to my question.  I have the code below, and simply would like to have my JQuery function to hide a **specific** row returned by the `foreach` loop.  **Currently it hides all rows returned**.  I'm using JQuery in .cshtml.  Please advise.

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">    

       $(document).ready(function(){
           $("input").click(function(){
               $("p").toggle(1000);
           });
       });

   </script>

   @foreach (var row in db.Query(selectQueryString)){    
       <p>First Name: @row.First_Name Last Name:@row.Last_Name</p> 
       <button>Toggle</button>
   }
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $(this).prev("p").toggle(1000);
});
```

[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vrNqh/)

**Edit**:

When you use `$("p")` as a selector in jquery you are actually getting all `<p>` tags; however, in your case you only wanted the one prior to each button. Therefore, you should the [prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) which gets the first instance of the `<p>` prior to the clicked button.

Comment: Great @Josh Mein, that worked. Thank you for the answer.  Could you briefly explain why the .prev is needed, or point me in the right direction?  Thanks Again.

Comment: @cholloway I have updated my answer describing why it is necessary. Welcome to Stackoverflow! :)